# Updating MySQL passwords for 5.6?

Tags: mysql, upgrade

A bit confused on this one.

Just about to upgrade MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6

There is a warning that many of the databases use old passords.

> The following users use pre-4.1-style MySQL passwords:
>
> We recommend that you update all of your accounts to longer MySQL
>   password hashes before you perform this upgrade. Failure to do so
>   could disrupt database access for accounts or applications that use
>   pre-4.1-style MySQL passwords.

I am not 100% sure what I need to do if anything.

Many of the accounts are not even databases.

I have tried to do a google search and not found anything helpful.

There is an option on cPanel to use pre 4.1 passwords, but that is not enabled, so not sure why this should flag up now, as I would expect issues, if I was using old passwords (whatever they might be).   That option goes away with 5.6 anyway.

Can anyone assist or give guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Execute below statement on your db-

```
SELECT USER,PASSWORD FROM mysql.user LIMIT 1;
```

If you are getting password length less than 41 suppose approx 16 it means you are using old password format and you need to change it to in new format which is of 41 length and more secure.

You can change your password format by below command-

```
set password for 'user'@'ip' = password ('new password');
```

Note: Before this you need to keep privileges tables backup. Also need to comment old_password option in your configuration file if it is on.

Comment: Speed up the finding process if you have a lot of users: `SELECT USER,PASSWORD FROM mysql.user WHERE LENGTH(PASSWORD) < 41`

Answer (score 0):

```
 For Windows, do this:

shell> mysql -u root
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('newpwd');

The last statement is unnecessary if the mysql.user table has no root account with a host value of %.

For Unix, do this:

shell> mysql -u root
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'host_name' = PASSWORD('newpwd');

You can also use a single statement that assigns a password to all root accounts by using UPDATE to modify the mysql.user table directly. This method works on any platform:

shell> mysql -u root
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')
    ->     WHERE User = 'root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> Take Reference from this link :-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: But that would not alter any of the other accounts surely?

I am not using old style pre 4.1 in cpanel, as that option is not selected, so am confused.

Comment: you should use these query . it's would works                                                                                                                                  UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;